# Prove for any sets $A$ and $B$, $2^{(A−B)} ⊆ (2^A −2^B )∪\{∅\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove for any sets A and B, $2^{(A−B)} ⊆ (2^A −2^B )∪\{∅\}$.

The hint given is: $∅ \notin 2^A −2^B$.

I can't seem to figure out how to go about this proof, some exploration would tell me that the statement does hold. I'm having a tough time translating this into proof language.

I can see that the statement must be true since there are combinations of elements that are not removed from the set difference of the power sets that makes the $2^{(A-B)}$ a subset.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Presumably you mean $(2^A - 2^B) \cup \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael formatting issue

Comment: Have you tried asking your professor in office hours?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of sets, $2^A$ means the set of all subsets of $A$.  So $2^{(A-B)}$ is the set of all subsets of $A-B$. The claim is that every subset of $A - B$ is either the empty set or a subset of $A$ that is not a subset of $B$.  And this is clearly true, because if $S$ is a nonempty subset of $A - B$,
its members (of which there is at least one) are all members of $A$ (so it's a subset of $A$) that are not members of $B$ (so it's not a subset of $B$).